# C# how does the :base class work when defining the subclass?

Tags: c#, parameters, subclass

So I am just trying to get my head around this concept here:

**Scenario 1**

I have a base class called Person and it has a single constrcutor with no parameters (i.e. the default constructor)

This class has 2 protected properties that I can change (they are public)

Now I want to create a subclass (call it student) that has one extra parameter, so I can create a constructor with 3 parameters (1 + 2 from the base class)

If I create an object of the subclass I can pass in 3 parameters - no problem this works (it might be wrong way to do it, but it works)

**Scenario 2**

I have a base class called Person and now I have a single constructor that takes 2 parameters, I do not have the default constructor with no parameters.

When I now create the sub class (student) that creates another parameter for its constructor.

This constructor only has a single parameter and I cannot add the second and third parameter from the base class like I did in scenario 1

However I can link the base class by using `:base()` but I need to pass in values as opposed to parameters.

**QUESTION**

How do I put in custom values in the `:base` class when I create a student object. Because I am passing in the values when I link it in the sub class constructor.

**Base class**

```
class Person
{
    protected string Name;
    protected int Age;

    //public Person1(){}

    public Person(string _name, int _age)
    {
        Name = _name;
        Age = _age;
    }

    public void SayHello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Helllo World!");
        Console.WriteLine($"My name is {Name} and I am {Age} years old");
    }
}
```

**Sub Class**

```
class Student : Person1
{
    private int StudentId;

    //I was hoping to put in new parameters in the base ()
    public Student(int _studentId) : base ("", 00)
    {
        //_name and _age do not exist
        //Name = _name;
        //Age = _age;
        StudentId = _studentId;
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p1 = new Person1("John", 45);
        p1.SayHello();


        var student1 = new Student(123456);
    }
```

But I don't know how to add the parameters that are set in my base class

Comment: When writing new constructor, compiler does not generate default parameterless constructor by default. so you have to write parameterless constructor in addition to other constructors in order to be able to call `base()`

Comment: So how can I customise those parameters when I create an object of the subclass? In another words using the example, how can I give student1 a different name then student2 if there is no parameter for it in the student class?

Comment: dirty way is to use static field to count numbers for you per instantiation. clean way is to use factory pattern, create a factory to handle initialization of your students

Comment: Could provide a code example as an answer?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I think you're really misinterpreting what OP is looking for.

Comment: @BJMyers OP is trying to make his library(?) more flexible, yes perhaps the answer is : don't make it that much flexible, you must pass student name and age any way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Student` constructor needs to take the parameters that will be passed to the `Person` base constructor.

```
class Student : Person
{
    private int StudentId;

    public Student(string name, int age, int studentId)
        : base(name, age)
    {
        StudentId = studentId;
    }
}
```

Comment: So are the student name and age parameters mapped to the base name and age here?

Comment: Think of the base constructor as a method that you are calling from the child constructor.  The `Student` constructor *calls* the `Person` constructor and passes in two arguments, as per the `Person` constructor signature.  The first argument is a string (referenced as `_name` in the base constructor), and the second argument is an integer (referenced as `_age` in the base constructor.

Comment: Awesome that makes so much more sense now :-) thanks for clarifying that for me.